# Changing the colour of all canvas items (rectangles) pressed by a mouse click and drag (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am designing an application for creating pixel art in Python. I currently have it so that the user can specify a required grid size (width * height) and it will create a grid of the specified height, with each grid square representing a point in a 2D list.

I used Tkinter's canvas widget and it's create_rectangle method to draw the grid, as the code excerpt shows.

I want to be able to click a grid square and drag my mouse, making the original clicked grid square and all of those which are dragged over by my mouse change colour.

A bit of research lead me to canvas tag_bind and bind, but neither of these seem to be able to allow me to implement the drag functionality I would like. The event.widget.findclosest method is very inaccurate.

Here is the code I have to draw the grid without any access to the onclick function.

```
 def drawGrid(self):
    for x in range(0, self.grid_width):
        for y in range(0, self.grid_height):
            x1 = (x * self.pixel_width)
            x2 = (x1 + self.pixel_width)
            y1 = (y * self.pixel_height)
            y2 = (y1 + self.pixel_height)
            self.grid[x,y] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    self.canvas.update()

def rectangleOnClick(event):
    #Colour the clicked square and all other squares that fall under mouse drag
```

Comment: not familiar w/ tkinter but something I have seen done elsewhere is tracking mouseup, mousedown along with having an object follow cursor location and using the collision detection between brush and object it is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create bindings that set a flag on button press, and release the flag on button release. You can set a binding on mouse motion that colors the item under the cursor when the flag is set.

It would look something like this:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self._dragging = False
        ...
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_click)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_release)

    def on_click(self, event):
        self._dragging = True
        self.on_move(event)

    def on_move(self, event):
        if self._dragging:
            items = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
            if items:
                rect_id = items[0]
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(rect_id, fill="red")

    def on_release(self, event):
        self._dragging = False
```

Comment: Fantastic! This worked perfectly. I can continue now after being stumped here for a day.

Thanks very much.